# D8 - How to access a custom block inside a main body of a node?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I can access to the node main body field, but I don't know how to access to the custom block inside that field.

```
$page = $node->load($nid);
$main_field = $page->get('field_main');
```

How can I access to a block inside the "$main_field" ?

Comment: I can access to the field "target_id" but still don't know how to access to the custom block field inside this field.

Comment: Try print_r($main_field) and see what you got there. But if you want to access data of some other block that is displayed together with your node on the same page - I think that node doesn't contain that information.